# how to get the age from the two dates in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery code like :

```
                   var date_time=elem.added_date;
                   var date = date_time.split(' ');
                   var dates=new Date();
                   var currentDate = dates.getFullYear()+"-"+(dates.getMonth()+1)+"-"+dates.getDate();
                  // alert(currentDate);
                   //alert(date[0]);
                   var age=currentDate-date[0];
```

> currentDate: is the currentdate comming like (2018-06-30)
>
> date[0] :in this i am getting the dob like (1988-01-30)

how can i get the age from the both of two values i am stuck here can anyone please help me related this

Comment: Please take the time to research your issue. This is a common question with an easy to find answer.

Comment: Actully i am newbie in jquery thats why i am asking @Rory McCrossan

Comment: All the more reason why you should be researching.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var years = moment().diff('1988-01-30', 'years');
```

---

or try this JS way way

```js
               
         var date_time=elem.added_date;
               var date = date_time.split(' ');
               var dates=new Date();
               var currentDate = dates.getFullYear()+"-"+(dates.getMonth()+1)+"-"+dates.getDate();
               var ageDifMs = new Date(currentDate) - new Date(date[0]).getTime();
               var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
               var age = Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
               console.log(age)
```

### Demo:

```js
var ageDifMs = new Date("2018-5-30") - new Date("1988-01-30 ").getTime();
                   var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
                   var age = Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
                   console.log(age)
```

Comment: This relies on the moment.js library

Comment: can u please update my question with your answer ???

Comment: i am not getting the age by my code can you please update my code ???

Comment: @Shruti Updated. Please check the snippet

Comment: showing age 0 for every case

Comment: Check your `currentDate` and `date[0]` are providing correct date

Comment: date[0]=2018-5-30 and currentdate is :1988-01-30

Comment: @Shruti you can check with my demo for those dates. It's working in this snippet.